# How to calculate illuminated surface area (not whole) of a mesh that has light shining on it?

Tags: mesh, light, lighting, 3d-printing

I want to represent a 3D mesh object which is cylindrical and has pores of different sizes on/in it. One or more lamps are shining on it. What I want to find out is the surface area that is illuminated, as only the surface that is illuminated is useful in my case (photocatalysis). Thank you.

Comment: this is just a guess, but this is what I'd probably try.  in blender, UV-map your cylinder, and then bake out the lighting to a texture map.   Then, take that baked map and put it through a tool like ImageMagick to calculate the percentage of white (i.e. light), as described here: https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19168

Comment: good idea, but I like staying in one program, so why not use the texture in a displace modifier?

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions. As I am completely new to the software, I have no clue what are you talking about. But I'll try to learn as fast as I can to see what I can do with your input. IN the meantime, could you expand your suggestions with more details if that's not the problem?